# regular expression to identify string with same beginning and ending characters

Tags: regex, string

What is a regular expression that will search for a string that has:
the same starting
and 
the same ending characters.

[........g:

the string always starts with [ and then has random characters but always ends with g:

Comment: Which language? Regular expression functions are different for every language.

Comment: Does [[].*g: works for you ?

Comment: in ruby, here you go: `/^\[(.+)g$/`

Comment: yes the first one above worked  ->   [[].*g:

Comment: Just FYI, `[[]` is an unusual way doing `\[`

Answer (score 2):

> The string always starts with **`[`** and then has random characters but always ends with **`g:`**

You can use this regex:

```
^\[.*g:$
```

If you meant the same starting and ending characters between `[` and `g:`, use this:

```
^\[(.+).*\1g:$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
\[.*?g:
```

This will match any chars between your delimiters.

The star quantifier in `.*?` is made "lazy" by the `?` so that the dot only matches as many characters as needed to allow the next token to match (shortest match). Without the `?`, the `.*` first matches the whole string, then backtracks only as far as needed to allow the next token to match (longest match).